# How do I delete the last row(which is all NULLs) in my database?

Tags: sql

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6
NULL    NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL
```

I have tried the following queries:

1.

```
Delete from tablename where column1 = NULL
```

2.

```
Delete from tablename where column1 IS NULL
```

The second query completed successfully but it said 0 rows affected.

Comment: #2 should work properly. #1 should "work", but never do anything because nothing ever equals null. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Heh, if by "last" row you mean the ONLY row, then you can delete without the wh^H^H, uh, no, I didn't say that.... Seriously, though, no idea why #2 is not working for you.  Are you sure it did not work?  select count(*) after you execute it.  Is the table empty?

Answer (score 3):

You must use the special syntax `is null` when attempting to match a null value:

```
delete from mytable
where Column1 is null
and Column2 is null
and Column3 is null
and Column4 is null
and Column5 is null
and Column6 is null;
```

Any regular comparison with `null` is always false,

eg both `Column1 = null` and `Column1 != null` are always `false`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this or equivalent for your rdbms should work.
It deletes rows if the return value of the isnull function is equal to an empty string.

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE isnull(Column1, '') = ''
```

Comment: and if `Column1` is an empty string, it'll do something you don't want

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE coalesce(col1,col2,col3,...) IS NULL
```